# Using infinite scroll in a Rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, infinite-scroll

I want my application to have an endless scroll. For that I'm using this javascript https://github.com/jney/jquery.pageless/blob/master/lib/jquery.pageless.js 
Then as he suggested in the usage I wrote added the pageless function in my script tag. But the application is failing to work. Am I doing this correctly?

```
                  <div id = "container1"></div>
                  <script>
                   $(document).ready(function() {
                       $.ajax({
                       url : "shirts/first",
                       type : "GET"
                       });
                       $("#name").autocomplete({
                        source : "shirts/autocomplete",
                        autoFocus : false,
                        minLength : 1,
                        select : function(event, ui) {
                             document.getElementById("name").value = ui.item.value;
                $.ajax({
                    url : "shirts/show?name=" + ui.item.value,
                    type : "GET"
                   });
                      }
                        });
                          $('#container1').pageless({ 
                     totalPages: 4,
                     url: 'shirts/first',
                     loaderMsg: 'Loading more results'
                     });
                      });


                          </script>
```

Controller code:

```
                      def first
                          @init = Sunspot.search(Clothes) do
                           paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 16
                           order_by :maxprice
                          end
                          @first = @init.results
                          if request.xhr?
                             sleep(1)
                             render :partial => 'shirts/first', :collection => @first
                           end 
                         end
```

Comment: Does your javascript console throw any errors? (If that name autocomplete part isn't necessary comment it out).

Answer (score 0):

first error i see is that you have defined the div with id #container1 but your jquery calls #container

also make sure you have the proper urls loading in that js. if this doesn't work, please provide more info

Comment: Yeah sorry, didn't see that. Actually I've used 'container1' itself. But when I run my app in a browser then my first page doesn't load. Only my 2nd and 3rd page keeps on loading again and again. I've edited my question and put in my controller code, see if it helps.